# Can I rely on the "Date: " email header?

Tags: smtp, email, eml

I've got a few maildirs I grabbed with getmail (both inbox and sent) and I want to give the eml files names that represent the date and time each mail has arrived (or was sent):

```
johnsmith@example.org-inbox-2015-07-28T20.02.14+0000.eml
```

(I want Windows to read the files, so no colons)

I've noticed that there is only one occurence of "Date: " inside the eml files:

```
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 20:02:14 +0000
```

Can I rely on this piece of header to rename the files? Is it reliable?

(I plan to write a posix or bash script for this task)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **nope**.

The `Date` header (and most of the other headers) is set by the client (and is not required), so it could be just anything or absent.

Spams appart, since the `Date` field is set by the MUA(/MSA) and still a lot of people are not synced with NTP or did not care to configure their working station properly, it is more than often wrong.
I also often see missconfigured automated mailer or MTA...

The date found in the `Received` headers is **slightly** more trustworthy because it is set by the realying MTA and the *probability* they are well configured is higher.

Note that except for the last one (the top-most in appearing order) which is your server (in your case GMail) they can be forged too.

Comment: I'm viewing an eml file and I'm seeing the exact opposite: `Received: from imap.gmx.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:993) by playbox.example.org with IMAP4-SSL; 19 Sep 2014 00:46:11 -0000` and `Date: Fri, 09 May 2014 02:18:17 +0200`. I received the mail on 2014-05-09 and I fetched it with getmail on 2014-09-19.

Comment: "slightly more trustworthy" — there is no guarantee that a Mail Transfer Agent will even have a clock set to the right century, and for some MTAs, there's good reason to assume they won't. For example, someone stuck this box in a closet in the 1990s and its hardware clock has gotten way out off but it still delivers the mail so no one even knows it exists.

Comment: getmail isn't an MTA but it modified the Received date! I'm reading this <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_retrieval_agent> and I think that I probably need to see some of its configuration options.